# mysql partial indexing, reverse indexing

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

I have a table with a list of words.

word VARCHAR(16)

I need to create a reverse index. ie. word "apple" would index as "elppa", word "banana" as "ananab" and so on.

Also, is it possible to index, say, a part of the word? Such as, skip the first/last 1 or 2 characters:

pple (apple)
anana (banana)

are these things possible?

Comment: Add a new column with the reverse text and build there the index.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create an index on a field that's limited by prefix-length, meaning that only the first n characters will be considered, you can't do it with an arbitrary start and end position though. Read more about it on mysql's [CREATE INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) documentation page.

In this case I'd just make another column, use mysql's [REVERSE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html) function to fill it in and create an index on it, that way you get a field to search on for the reverse of the original word.

Other databases such as Postgresql allow you to [index an expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-createindex.html), which would effectively allow you to index `reverse(col_name)` without creating the extra column. So it it's possible, just not with mysql right now. (since version 9 potgresql has reverse() native I believe)

Comment: MySQL 8 using innodb can index a virtual generated column. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html

Comment: Also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html for more on generated columns.