# Can I create a MySQL index for LIKE searches with both left and right wildcards?

Tags: mysql, search, indexing, sql-like

I’m using MySQL 5.5.37.  I have a table with a column

```
`NAME` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
```

and I intend to have partial searches on the name column like

```
select * FROM organnization where name like ‘%abc%’
```

Note that I want to search that the string “abc” occur anywhere, not necessarily at the beginning.  Given this, is there any index I can use on the column to optimize query execution?

Comment: No, this isn't possible. Maybe what you want is a full-text index?

Comment: I'm confused -- you say its not possible and then you suggest a way it might be possible?  Could you provide an answer with an example of how it would be possible?

Comment: full-text indexes can match words, not random strings.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: Yes, what will be searched is not necessarily a word, it could be only part of a word.

Comment: Then it's not possible. Regular indexes are B-trees, they optimize searching from the beginning of the value.

Comment: The storage necessary for an index that could optimize finding a string anywhere in the value would be excessive. It would have to have entries for each character in each value.

Comment: [This should help a bit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957053/mysql-partial-indexing-reverse-indexing)

Comment: @N.B., I'm not fully connecting the dots on the SO question you referenced.  I'm happy to create an extra column that is a reverse of the NAME column but I don't see how that helps me with my indexing problem.

Comment: 10K rows in the original table is not too slow to do `LIKE '%abc%'` against.  How many rows will the table eventually have?

Comment: There are about 100k rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect a few matching results only, you can still create index on the name column to speed up queries, with help of a primary key.

If your table have a primary key like

org_id int not null auto_increment primary key,
name varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
desc varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
size int,
....

you can create an index on (name, org_id)

and do your query like this:

```
select * from orgnizations o1 join (select org_id from orgnizations where name like '%abcd%' ) o2 using (org_id)
```

should be faster than your original query

if you only need one or two other columns for the name searching, you can include those columns in your name index and do queries like

```
select org_id, name, size from orgnizations where name like '%abcd%'
```

will still be much faster then the full table scan

Comment: I have no expectation on the number of results.  It could be few, but it could be many.

Comment: As long as your '%abcd%' search returns relatively small data set, you should do an index scan instead of table scan. The real threshold depends on your data but if you expect that most searches will match less than 10% of the records, index scan can be helpful. But it is not perfect and can still take some time to complete. If you want to search multiple million records table in sub seconds, you may need build an index using a keyword table, similar to full-text indexing.